# Find all files named *.txt in directory

Tags: python, filenames, glob

```
import os, glob

file = os.listdir("my directory: example")

mp3files = list(filter(lambda f: f == '*.txt',file))    
print(mp3files)
```

This code is giving me only : `[]`

Comment: Hint: make use of the `glob` module you're importing. :)

Comment: Your `lambda f: f == '*.txt'` was literally comparing each filename to see if it matched <asterisk>.txt, hence they all failed and you got empty-list. \* is only a wildcard when some function e.g. regex, string, glob etc. treats it as a wildcard. Otherwise it's a literal *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mp3files = list(filter(lambda f: f.endswith('.txt') ,file))
```

Should work, since the file name do not match (`==`) to `*.txt` but rather end with that extension

Comment: Thank you a lot , I really appreciate help

Answer (score 1):

From Python 3.4 upwards you can use just those two lines for that task:

```
from pathlib import Path
mp3files = list(Path('.').glob('**/*.txt'))
```

More info: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.endswith`:

```
list(filter(lambda f: f.endswith('.txt'),file))
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use the glob module that you have imported ?

```
mp3files = glob.glob('*.txt')
```

this will return a list of all mp3 files in your current working directory.
if your files are in a different directory and not in your cwd:

```
path_to_files_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'your_files_dir_name', '*.txt')

mp3files = glob.glob(path_to_files)
```

Comment: Good solution but he's looking for *.txt files.

Comment: yep, that's right i've changed the extension from mp3 to txt, thank you

Comment: I know about glob but my task was to use functions filter and lambda